# How to convert 1x1 numpy.ndarray fields to float numbers

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df`, in which col1 contains float numbers. After some processing float numbers are somehow converted to 1x1 `numpy.ndarray`. How can I convert them back to simple float numbers?

```
df['col1'] = df_temp['col1'].values[ind.ravel()]
print df['col1']

[0.145833333333]
[0.247222222222]
[0.181944444444]

print type(df['col1'])
   <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: you could explicitly convert them with `float(df['col1'][0])`. as for your original question, they were never floats to begin with so youre not really converting them "back" to floats

Comment: @R Nar: Great! It works.